# The console output is a mess while executing 'npm install' in child_process.exec

Tags: node.js, npm

The console output looks good while executing directly in Gitbash as following:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@1.4.14
npm info using node@v0.10.29
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 12:38:21
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
npm info installOne phonegap@3.5.0-0.20.4
...
...
```

But, if i do the same thing programmatically in nodejs, code snippet as below:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var process = exec('npm install -g phonegap', function(err, stdout, stderr){

});

process.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.info(data);
});

process.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    console.error(data);
});
```

The console output looks a mess like this:

```
npm

info

it worked if it ends with
ok
npm info using npm@1.4.14
npm info using
node@v0.10.29

npm

info
 trying
 registry request attempt 1 at 12:44:09
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap

npm

http
 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
...
...
```

Is there any way to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`console.log` and `console.error` append a newline character after the data they output, and you are calling them for every `data` event. That means that even if the `data` event is only part of a line, it gets it's own line.

Instead, you should be writing the data directly to `stdout` so that it doesn't add random newlines. I'd also not use the name `process` since that is already the name of a global.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var phonegap = exec('npm install -g phonegap', function(err, stdout, stderr){

});
phonegap.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
phonegap.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The data event does not correspond to a complete line of text.  Use process.stdout.write instead of console.info.  This way each write will continue on the same line until you explicitly write a \n.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination